# Perform JavaScript function based on location in page (cells)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, datalist

I have a page that collects, which classes students are going to take and displays both the `Course Title` and the `Catalog Number` in a table. If the student selects a `Course Title`, it will automatically fill in what the `Catalog Number` is in the next cell, and vice-versa.

The only problem I'm having is, when you fill in one `Course Title`, it fills every single `Catalog Number` cell there is (and vice-versa).

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()">
          <datalist id="courses" name="courseDatalist">
  <!--Filled in script-->     
   </datalist>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()">
          <datalist id="catalogs" name="catalogDatalist">
  <!--Filled in script-->
   </datalist>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
        <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
        <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
        <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="testTemplateJS.js"></script>
  <script>
    //Course Names
    var courseNames = ["Class A", "Class B", "Class C", "Class D", "Class E"];
    var list = $('#courses')[0];

    courseNames.forEach(function(item) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = item;
      list.appendChild(option);
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    //Catalog Numbers
    var catNumbers = ["Catalog 1", "Catalog 2", "Catalog 3", "Catalog 4", "Catalog 5"];
    var list = $('#catalogs')[0];

    catNumbers.forEach(function(item) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = item;
      list.appendChild(option);
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function UpdateCatNumbers() {
      //on change of courseInput, run...
      $("input[name=courseInput]").change(function() {
        //declare a as the array index # of courseNames
        var a = courseNames.indexOf($(this).val());
        //change catalog input to display the same array index of catNumbers
        $("input[name=catalogInput]").val(catNumbers[a]);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function UpdateCourseNames() {
      $("input[name=catalogInput]").change(function() {
        var b = catNumbers.indexOf($(this).val());
        $("input[name=courseInput]").val(courseNames[b]);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

How do I get it so the `UpdateCatNumbers()` and `UpdateCourseNames()` functions only populate the cell directly next to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to apply the value to one other input only. In this case you can use jQuery `eq(index)` - with it you can select single element from a jQuery collection based on an index:

```
$("input[name=courseInput]").each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var a = courseNames.indexOf($(this).val());

        $("input[name=catalogInput]").eq(index).val(catNumbers[a]);
    )};
});
```

Comment: The only problem is when I assign 'a' to eq(index) it references the index of the datalist array, not the specific input. Any thoughts on how to specify that it is referencing the index of the input box?

Comment: Edited - wrapped in $.each to get the `index` based on the jQuery collection.